# Show that $N_n \mid N_m$ if and only if $n \mid m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $N_n$ be an integer formed of $n$ consecutive $1$s. For example $N_3 = 111,$ $N_7 = 1 111 111.$ Show that $N_n \mid N_m$ if and only if $n \mid m.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$N_n=\frac{10^n-1}9$$

Bill Dubuque [once proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1/7561#7561) the following

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of integers with $f_0=0$ such that, when $m>n$; we have $$f_n\equiv f_{n-m}\mod f_m$$ Then $(f_n,f_m)=f_{(n,m)}$

Apply this to any sequence of the form $$\hat a_n=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$$ to prove the claim $\hat a_n\mid \hat a_m\iff n\mid m$. In your case $a=10$.

Comment: Steven, since you're new, you may not be aware of this: when you find an answer to be particularly helpful, we encourage you to accept it. (But you can only accept **one** answer per question.) To *accept* an answer, just click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept!

Comment: Nice, Peter! $+1$

Comment: +1 You don't need something that strong. You can show that $\gcd( a^n -1, a^m -1 ) = a^{\gcd(n,m)} - 1 $, which gives the result immediately.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sure, but what you give is a special case of this, and the proof of the above is not hard. Also, I wanted to link to one of Bill's many nice answers.

Comment: Yea, i know it's a special case (and both have similar proofs). However, the general case is often rarely used, which this special case is often used.

Comment: how do you show that Calvin?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that $\,f_n\,$ satisfies $\, f_n \equiv f_{n-m}\pmod{f_m}\,$ for $\,m > n,\,$ hence, by mimicing the Euclidean algorithm, one easily deduces that $\,\gcd(f_m,f_n) = f_{\gcd(m,n)}.\,$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7479/78535) for more.