# $(p^m-1) \mid (p^n-1) \Leftrightarrow m \mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $(p^m-1) \mid (p^n-1) \Leftrightarrow m \mid n$.
The $\Leftarrow$ part is ok, the $\Rightarrow$ part should be easy but I'm stuck with it!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I started writing $p^n-1=a(p^m-1)$ but I wasn't able to arrive at the conclusion I want...

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Comment: OK I got it, thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing that $a^n - 1 \mid a^m - 1 \iff n \mid m$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413473/showing-that-an-1-mid-am-1-iff-n-mid-m)

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the fact that, given integers $a>b>0$, then $(a^n-b^n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a [divisibility sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence) (see also this [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.2416.pdf) on Arxiv).

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=mq+r$ where $0<r<m$ and consider modulo $p^m-1$

Answer (score 0):

We are required to prove:

> If $p^m-1\mid p^n-1$, then $m\mid n$

We can state this in an equivalent contrapositive

> If $m\nmid n$, then $p^m-1\nmid p^n-1$

We can prove the second statement by contradiction:

Assume there exist integers $m, n$ such that $m\nmid n$, but $p^m - 1 \mid  p^n - 1$. How will you prove this?

Comment: How is this not just restating the problem?  This doesn't seem to provide guidance in how to take a step forward...

Comment: It does. In a mathematical sense, everything is just restating the problem. Additionally, a lot of theorems have been proved by actually proving their contrapositives. Take the Steiner-Lehmus problem, for example.