# prove $(2^a − 1) \bmod (2^b − 1) = 2^{a \bmod b} − 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

The question is

> Show that if $a$ and $b$ are both positive integers, then $(2^a − 1) \bmod (2^b − 1) = 2^{a \bmod b} − 1$. [1]

**attempt.** clearly this holds when when $a=b$ and $a<b$. However I find it hard to prove for when $a>b$. Let $a=qb+r$ where $q\ge 1,0\le r<b$. I also used $2$ properties, first one is that $(2^b-1)$ divides $2^{(n+1)b}-2^{nb}$ because
$$
2^{(n+1)b}-2^{nb}=2^{nb}(2^b-1)
$$
and the second property is that we can break $2^a-1$ into
$$
2^a-1 = \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} 2^i = s_0+s_1+...+s_{q}
$$
where
$$
s_n=\sum_{i=nb}^{(n+1)b-1} 2^i = 2^{(n+1)b}-2^{nb},\quad n=0,...,q-1
$$
and
$$
s_{q} = \sum_{i=qb}^{qb+r-1} 2^i = 2^{qb+r}-2^{qb} = 2^{qb}(2^r-1)
$$
now by first property we know $2^b-1$ divides $s_0+...+s_{q-1}$, the remainder seems to be
$s_{q} = 2^{qb}(2^r-1) = 2^{qb}(2^{a \bmod b} − 1)$ which is not exactly $2^{a \bmod b} − 1$ but a multiple of it ... so I failed to prove it

[1] Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, Kenneth H. Rosen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that $\gcd(2^m - 1, 2^n - 1) = 2^{\gcd(m,n )} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225289/proving-that-gcd2m-1-2n-1-2-gcdm-n-1) Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473), or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413473)?

Comment: You should split $\sum_{i=0}^{a-1} 2^i$ in a reversed manner: try use $q$ complete blocks from $2^{a-1}$ to below, and the final block with $r$ elements.

Comment: [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) $\,A\bmod B = \bar A\iff [\![1]\!]\ \ A\equiv \bar A\pmod{\!B}\,$ and $\ [\![2]\!]\ \ 0\le \bar A < B.\,$ Here $\,A = 2^a-1,\ $ $B = 2^b-1,\ $ $\bar A = 2^{a\bmod b}-1.\,$ Here $\,[\![2]\!]\,$ is clear, and $\,[\![1]\!]$ follows by [mod order reduction,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) i.e. $\!\bmod 2^b-1\!:\ 2^b\equiv 1\Rightarrow 2^a\equiv 2^{a\bmod b}\ \ $